# Botframework | Direct Line | Attachment Upload - Need more info about limitations, security and storage

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have a few questions regarding Attachment upload on direct line (webchat)

When the user uploads a file on web chat

- What storage is being used ?

  - Can we use our own storage ?
- What are the limitations ?

  - Size limits
  - Allowed File types
  - etc.
- What about security ?

  - I noticed that we can upload anything from an image to an executable

Thank you,

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments for Direct Line are stored encrypted on Microsoft servers. The size limit currently is 20MB and the contents will be available for 24 hours. You can use links to resources (actually how you would get around size limits) instead of through the Direct Line storage, but there is no way to override the Direct Line storage if you are sending actual attachments. I don't believe there are any restrictions on file types within Direct Line.

Comment: Could you please share the reference for these info. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any public resources. This was conveyed to me from high level folks within Bot Framework services team.